# SwiftUI View Not Updating When @State Changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

I'm really struggling to get a simple SwiftUI text view to update when using @State. Code below. Any help appreciated (I'm sure it's something daft but I'm new to all this - can't even copy/paste the code snippet correctly). Thank you.

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var tappedToggle: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("First: \(printRandomFactoid())").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.tappedToggle.toggle()
            Text("Latest... \r \(printRandomFactoid())").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View should never be inside action closure... The intention probably was

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var tappedToggle: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Text(tappedToggle ? "First: \(printRandomFactoid())" : "Latest... \r \(printRandomFactoid())")
           .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
           .onTapGesture {
              self.tappedToggle.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```